# Symfony2 create new entity element in the form itself

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am using SonataAdminBundle and in the form I want to display some mapped information. My main object Skin is mapped with CmsElemnt, in witch the content is saved. I need to acces it in the form to be able to update it.

I have this mapped information:

Skin.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CmsElement", mappedBy="content")
 */
private $navbar;
```

CmsElement.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Skin", inversedBy="navbar")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $content;
```

I tried using the symfony dcumentation Here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object

So I created a service to load the CmsElement information:

```
class SkinElementType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('content', 'textarea'); 
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\CmsElement',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'skin_element_type_cms';
    }
}
```

Registered it:

```
skin_element_type_cms:
    class: Mp\ShopBundle\Form\Type\SkinElementType
    tags:
        -  { name: form.type }
```

Now in the skin admin I do this:

```
    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
//            ->add('id', 'hidden')
              ->add('name')
            ->add('status', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('skin_element_type_cms', new CmsElement(), array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array('cols' => '8', 'rows' => '8')))
}
```

I get this error:

```
Please define a type for field `skin_element_type_cms` in `Mp\ShopBundle\Admin\SkinAdmin`
```

Comment: use $this->createFormBuilder() in controller to create forms and handle them

Comment: I am using SonataAdminBundle

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a custom form to manage your relations. You can use the sonata_type_collection to manage oneToMany relations.

**SkinAdmin.php**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('status', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('navbar', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table'
        ))
   ;
}
```

Check the official documentation for more details : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-one-to-many